# Data updated but not displayed on the php page

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

This is the code that may help solving my problem
**isset values:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['length']))
    {       
    include 'class.cpn.php';
    $no_of_cpns = $_POST['no_of_cpns'];
    $length = $_POST['length'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $coupons =coupon::generate_coupons($no_of_.........ls,$rad......omr, $mask);
```

**display section:**

```
    foreach ($coupons as $key => $value) 
         {
    echo $value."\n" ;         // it stores the result in array form   
         }
    $val = serialize($value); //serializing the value and storing in $val
```

**database query:**

```
    $firstinsert ="update checker 
                   set op = '==' , value = '".$val."' 
                   where attribute = '".$password."'" ;
        $query = mysql_query($firstinsert) or die(mysql_error());
        header("location: codegen.php");    
    }
?>
```

Comment: I guess you want to `UPDATE` not `INSERT`!!

Comment: 1. `check` is a reserved keyword and you need to backtick that `` in the query. 2. `Insert into... where` is a wrong syntax. 3. Read some mysql tutorial on how to write insert and update query.

Comment: your query should be " update `check` set op = '==' , value = '".$val."' where attribute = '".$password."'" ;

Comment: @GautamBhatt:   Try and respond *Bhatt Saheb*.

Comment: the update query worked and value is inserted but there came  another problem now it is not displaying the value on my  php page.

Comment: This is not a problem. Update your question with your view code @GautamBhatt

Comment: any updates for this display error